# Form Elements Pasted in Reverse Sequence

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a form in Visual Studio 2012. There are multiple labels ranging from `Label1` to `Label10` arranged vertically. I need to copy these labels next to the first set of labels such that I have `Label11` to `Label20` next to the first set. However when I copy/paste the form elements they are pasted vertically in a reversed sequence i.e `Label20` in front of `Label1` and `Label19` in front of `Label2`, I don't want the sequence to get reversed when I paste the form elements.

I remember it working fine when I tried it on VS2015, but now I'm on VS2012 and it doesn't works as expected. Based on Google search results this doesn't appear to be a common question.

Comment: This is just a guess but it may depend on the order in which you select them.  That said, it shouldn't matter because you should be renaming all your controls from the default anyway.  Any form with controls named `Label1`, `Label2`, etc, is a bad form.

Comment: Order in which I select them doesn't affect the behaviour. There will be many of these elements and the default names with incrementing numbers would serve the purpose well for the programming logic I have planned. But I guess I'll have to do with renaming each element manually if there isn't a workaround for this. I already tried applying Update 5 thinking this might address it but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you place 3 buttons on a form and copy and paste them they will be in reverse order `**(ex. button1, button2, button3) = (button6, button5, button4)**`.

After pasting, in order to make them paste in ascending order you must change the index order by clicking `button3` and select bring to the front, button2 and select Bring to the front, button1 and select Bring to the front; then copy them all at once and then paste and the paste order should be button4, button5 and button6 and so on.

**hope this helps.**

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the z-Index of your copied controls.
If you add 2 new labels with the VS designer to your form in `InitializeComponent()` will be this code:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
```

If you copy and paste them it will result in:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
```

where label3 is the copy of label2 and label4 is the copy of label1.

If you fix the z-Index of your labels (right-click on them in the designer and use 'Bring to front'/'Send to back') it will become:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
```

Now, when you copy and paste them you'll get:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
```

where label3 is the copy of label1 and label4 is the copy of label2.

Btw, this behaves all the same in VS2010, VS2012 and VS2015